# Remove space between two trapezoids

Tags: html, css

For some reason there's space between my trapezoids.

```css
#trapezoid {
    margin-top: 100px;
 border-bottom: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 200px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    float: left;
}

#trapezoid2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
 border-bottom: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 200px;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid2"></div>
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Is there a way to remove the space without using negative margin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because elements still keep it's DOM flow when you do `transform:rotate(-90deg);`. If you remove it, you will see that two divs actually touches. You can move second element to reduce gap.

```css
#trapezoid {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  float: left;
  
  /* Added code */
  position: relative;
  right: 140px;
}
#trapezoid2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid2"></div>
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Comment: Where does 140px come from?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of making the trapezoid horizontally and then rotating, just make it the way you want it.

```css
#trapezoid {
  margin-top:20px;
  border-left:100px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#trapezoid2 {
  margin-top:20px;
  border-right:100px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
  <div id="trapezoid2"></div>
  <div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do it without the rotating:

```
#trapezoid {
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0px;
  float: left;
}

#trapezoid2 {
  border-right: 100px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wxzdrv

Answer (score 3):

That gap is there because of `width` and `transform: rotate`, but you can use `translateY` to fix it.

```css
#trapezoid {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(70px);
  float: left;
}
#trapezoid2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(70px);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid2"></div>
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Comment: where does 70px come from?

Comment: Well the gap is around 140px and i think that is result of `400-(140+140) = 120` but that 120 when transformed create gap of around 140, but i am not sure about this.